# Como vários containers Docker atendem a mesma URL (microserviços)

Tags: docker, microsserviços

Estou iniciando com Docker e com aplicar com microserviços e fiquei com uma dúvida, como instância do meu micro serviço que sobe tem um novo IP, como faço para que ao chamar uma única URL eu consiga distribuir as requisições entre os diversos containers do meu serviço?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eles não atendem diretamente. Há um intermediador, que pode ser um load balancer ou um proxy reverso.

Em um deploy docker, dificilmente você usa diversas portas, você em geral usa apenas as portas 80 e 443 se estivermos falando de tráfego http.

O roteamento dentro da infra do docker é feito a partir desse princípio, onde hospedamos um proxy reverso escutando essas portas, e o proxy reverso tem as configurações de roteamento e distribuição para cada cenário.

Produtos/Projetos comuns nesse papel:

- NGINX
- Traefik
- HAProxy
- Envoy